# Convert JSON data to a table(Matrix like) in Angularjs with extra columns added and dynamic headers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have the below Json object which I want to convert to the table exactly as described below with total, percentage columns and the header should be dynamically printed using ng-repeat.

```js
$scope.Data = [{
    Year: 2014,
    Month: Jan,
    Location: "LocationA",
    Value: 201
  },
  {
    Year: 2015,
    Month: Feb,
    Location: "LocationB",
    Value: 560
  },
  {
    Year: 2014,
    Month: Jan,
    Location: "LocationC",
    Value: 320
  },
  {
    Year: 2015,
    Month: Feb,
    Location: "LocationD",
    Value: 240
  }

]
```

[image]

Comment: Any update please.

Comment: Can someone please help me with the above.